# Can public users sign up for a Chatter Communities account?

Tags: community

Is it possible to allow the general public to sign up for a Chatter Communities account? I'm thinking something like Force.com Sites public page with Communities surfaced through a Customer Portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can allow self-registration for Communities, but that you'll need a license for the users.

Comment: Licenses are fine, I expect that. Do you know of any documentation that I could refer to?

Comment: I'll check, but I've just been talking to my Account Exec about a possible use case and self-registration is a requirement for us.

Comment: The FAQ may be of help: http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/communities/faq/

Comment: I can't find any info about the licenses available for Communities, I'm not sure why its such a secret. @WesNolte were you ever able to find a list?

Comment: Kind of. If you check the Summer 13 release notes they mention that all previous portal license types are still available in addition to the two new Partner and Customer Community licenses. There's more info here: http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm